# Как сделать componentWillUnmount в хуках

Tags: javascript, reactjs

При использовании react portal создает див, куда кладется компонент, но при исчезновении(on Unmount), в DOM остается пустой див. Не красивенько, как исправить?

```js
import { useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import {} from './styles';
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom';

const CollectionPreviewItem = ( { component } ) => {
  const el = useMemo(()=>document.createElement ( 'div' ),[]);
  useEffect ( () => {
    document.body.appendChild ( el );
  }, [ el ] );

  return (
    createPortal ( component, el )
  );
};

export default CollectionPreviewItem;
```

Comment: Хук useEffect должен возвратить функцию, которая и будет вызываться при исчезновении элемента

Comment: `return *;` - то, что вам нужно (в useEffect)

Comment: @Denis Bubnov помогите пожалуйста https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1109017/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-jest-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хук `useEffect` представляет собой совокупность методов жизненного цикла React, таких как `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, и `componentWillUnmount`.

> Если вы хотите запустить эффект и сбросить его только один раз (при
>   монтировании и размонтировании), вы можете передать пустой массив
>   (`[]`) вторым аргументом. React посчитает, что ваш эффект не зависит
>   от каких-либо значений из пропсов или состояния и поэтому не будет
>   выполнять повторных запусков эффекта. Это не обрабатывается как особый
>   случай — он напрямую следует из логики работы входных массивов.

[Условное срабатывание эффекта](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect): по-умолчанию эффекты запускаются после каждого завершённого рендера. Таким образом, эффект всегда пересоздаётся, если значение какой-то из зависимости изменилось. Однако в некоторых случаях это может быть излишним, чтобы реализовать это (не выполнять эффект каждый раз), передайте второй аргумент в `useEffect`, который является массивом значений, от которых зависит эффект.

Вот тут мы и подобрались к самому интересному - [очистка эффекта](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect). Часто эффекты создают ресурсы, которые необходимо очистить (или сбросить) перед тем, как компонент покидает экран, например подписку или идентификатор таймера. Чтобы сделать это, функция переданная в `useEffect`, может вернуть функцию очистки. То есть, если из хука `useEffect` вернуть функцию - она будет вызвана во время размонтирования (`componentWillUnmount`), вот так:

```
useEffect(() => {
  document.body.appendChild(el);

  return () => {
    // Делайте в этом блоке что нужно, это и есть `componentWillUnmount`
  };
}, [el]);
```

Функция очистки запускается до удаления компонента из пользовательского интерфейса, чтобы предотвратить утечки памяти. Кроме того, если компонент рендерится несколько раз (как обычно происходит), предыдущий эффект очищается перед выполнением следующего эффекта.

Также рекомендую ознакомиться с [порядком срабатывания эффектов](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#timing-of-effects). В отличие от `componentDidMount` и `componentDidUpdate`, функция, переданная в `useEffect`, запускается во время отложенного события после разметки и отрисовки.

Изменение DOM, которое видно пользователю, должно запускаться синхронно до следующей отрисовки, чтобы пользователь не замечал визуального несоответствия. Для этих типов эффектов React предоставляет один дополнительный хук, называемый [**`useLayoutEffect`**](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect). Советую обратить ваше внимание на этот хук.

Для ознакомления, хороший ответ по хукам: [How to use componentWillMount() in React Hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53465182/5275890)

Comment: помогите пожалуйста   https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1109017/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-jest-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82